# cll parameters in Yelp API iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, yelp

I am trying to integrate Yelp's search and business APIs into my app. However, i'm running into some issues. I want to give the yelp geocoder a businesses latitude and longitude. According to Yelps Developer website

[image: How to add CLL param]

This is very vague and I don't really know what/ how to implement the cll parameters. 
Here is the yelp api i'm using

[image]

[image]

I don't really know where/how to implement these cll parameters, so any help with that would be great. For the full API i'm using, you can access it here: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/objective-c

Any help would be greatly appreciated!