# How to convert CLLCoordinate2D lat/long into NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, nsnumber

I'm trying to use Yelp API, and i'm trying to have the lat/long as the params for the API search. However, it does not take the type `double`, it only accepts Objective-C objects. Having no knowledge in Objective-C, what do you suggest the type for the parameter of lat and long be? I tried NSNumber, but when i try to turn my lat/long coordinates of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to an NSNumber that takes in a double, its value is nil

Here is my Yelp API that I am using:

```
- (void)queryTopBusinessInfoForTerm:(NSString *)term location:(NSString *)location latitude:(NSNumber *)latitude longitude:(NSNumber *)longitude completionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *topBusinessJSON, NSError *error))completionHandler {

  NSLog(@"Querying the Search API with term \'%@\' and location \'%@'", term, location);

  //Make a first request to get the search results with the passed term and location
  NSURLRequest *searchRequest = [self _searchRequestWithTerm:term location:location latitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
  [[session dataTaskWithRequest:searchRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

if (!error && httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {

  NSDictionary *searchResponseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
  NSArray *businessArray = searchResponseJSON[@"businesses"];

  if ([businessArray count] > 0) {

    NSDictionary *firstBusiness = [businessArray firstObject];
    NSString *firstBusinessID = firstBusiness[@"id"];
    NSLog(@"%lu businesses found, querying business info for the top result: %@", (unsigned long)[businessArray count], firstBusinessID);

    [self queryBusinessInfoForBusinessId:firstBusinessID completionHandler:completionHandler];
  } else {
    completionHandler(nil, error); // No business was found
  }
} else {
  completionHandler(nil, error); // An error happened or the HTTP response is not a 200 OK
}
  }] resume];
}
```

And here is the params

```
- (NSURLRequest *)_searchRequestWithTerm:(NSString *)term location:(NSString *)location latitude:(NSNumber *) latitude longitude:(NSNumber *)longitude {
  NSDictionary *params = @{
                       @"term": term,
                       @"location": location,
                       @"cll": latitude,
                       @"cll": longitude,
                       @"limit": kSearchLimit
                       };

  return [NSURLRequest requestWithHost:kAPIHost path:kSearchPath params:params];
}
```

And here is my current Swift method calling the Query from YelpAPi:

```
func yelpApi() {
    var latitude = NSNumber(double: businessStreetAddress.latitude)
    var longitude = NSNumber(double: businessStreetAddress.longitude)
    var searchTerm: NSString = "Asian Food";
    var defaultLocation: NSString = "New York"
    var APISample:YPAPISample = YPAPISample();

    var requestGroup:dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create();


    APISample.queryTopBusinessInfoForTerm(searchTerm as String, location: defaultLocation as String, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) { (topBusinessJSON: [NSObject: AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if((error) != nil) {
            println("Error happened during the request" + error.localizedDescription);
        } else if((topBusinessJSON) != nil) {
            println("Top business info",topBusinessJSON);
        } else {
            println("No business was found");
        }

        dispatch_group_leave(requestGroup);
    }

    dispatch_group_wait(requestGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


}
```

Comment: please describe more ( show your method (yelp api) , current var

Comment: Check the edited question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to `NSNumber`, You cannot have it in a single `NSNumber`. You can convert to two `NSNumber` objects like follows:

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D location; // This is the location you have.
 NSNumber *latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.latitude];
 NSNumber *longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.longitude];
```

with Modern ObjC you can covert as:

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D location; // This is the location you have.
 NSNumber *latitude = @(location.latitude);
 NSNumber *longitude = @(location.longitude);
```

and call your

```
NSURLRequest *searchRequest = [self _searchRequestWithTerm:term location:location latitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
```

Don't confuse with the variable named like `location` which just I have named it. because your function `searchRequestWithTerm:location:latitude:longitude:` is having one parameter named `location` which accepts `NSString`.

This may help you.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to solve this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604208/cll-parameters-in-yelp-api-ios